# Signup one website and use same id to access course in moodle

Tags: moodle

i created a course in moodle. I have a website when any student signup in these website and pay for course then only those student will able to access these course who pay for the course no other can access it

Comment: How is this a programming related question?

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to use cohorts to manage users who can access a course.

Create a cohort, for a group of courses or for a particular course - https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/Cohorts

Add users to the cohort who have paid - you can do this manually or with code.

For example using `function cohort_add_member($cohortid, $userid)` in `/cohort/lib.php`

Then use the cohort sync enrolment method on the course, this will automatically enrol the users from the cohort onto the course - https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/Cohort_sync